# Como dercargo imagen contenida en PictureBox con base de datos en C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015, picturebox

tengo una duda que no puedo resolver y busco de su ayuda...

Les comento, tengo un datagrid el cual tiene una columna tipo imagen en la cual uso como vista previa de mi imagen que se carga desde una base de datos.

Seguido tengo una columna tipo button el cual me sirve para Ver la imagen en un PictureBox, todo esto funciona correctamente puedo ver todas las imágenes en el picturebox cuando pulso el botón Ver.

Despues tengo una columna tipo button para elimiar la imagen, eso funciona correctamente.

Después tengo una columna tipo button el cual tiene un botón que es para Descargar la imagen que tenga el picturebox y aquí es el problema.

Aquí la imagen de datagrid
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Aquí tengo el código de como al pulsar el botón ver la imagen pasa al picturebox

```
DataGridViewImageCell cell = 
dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["vistaprev"] as DataGridViewImageCell;
Bitmap bmpbt;
bmpbt = (Bitmap)cell.Value;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
bmpbt.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
base64dgv = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

MemoryStream msm = new  MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64dgv));
pictureBox2.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
pictureBox2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
}
```

Así estoy intentando descargar las imágenes...

```
SaveFileDialog newsave = new SaveFileDialog();
            newsave.FileName ="Name";
            newsave.Filter = "JPEG(*.JPEG)|*.JPEG";


            if (newsave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                pictureBox2.Image.Save(newsave.FileName,ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
```

Esto me descarga una imagen pero cuando la abro no se visualiza la imagen, solo asi nombre.jpeg y cuando le doy doble cilck para ver la imagen no se ve nada.

Pueden orientarme de como hacerlo.

Gracias.

Nota: La imagen se carga de la base de datos, NUNCA LE PASO LA RUTA DE LA IMAGEN AL PICTUREBOX, no nos confundamos.

Comment: porque conviertes la imagen a base64 y despues nuevamente a binary ? eso esta de mas

Comment: Gracias por la observacion, sin embargo eso como ayuda a que pueda guardar la imagen?

Comment: con la respuesta que proporcione puede simplificar la implementacion introduciendo menos errores, tambien valida si el formato de la imagen es el correcto, quizas este guardando como jpg pero en la db la imagen es de un formato diferente

Comment: grecias por la recomendacion, lo tomare en cuenta ya que en la BD se pueden guardar imagenes PNG, JPEG, JPG entonces si me convendria quizas validar que tipo de imagen es la que estoy guardando desde el picturebox, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recomendaría que no des tantos pasos, si tienes la imagen en el `Bitmap` de allí ya puedes grabar la imagen en un archivo

```
bmpbt.Save(newsave.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

[Bitmap.Save(String, ImageFormat)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.5#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_)